# Drupal 7 - Show hierarchical taxonomy terms in a field of a view

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-taxonomy

In Drupal 7 I have a categories taxonomy vocabulary with the following structure:

```
-Cat one
-Cat two
---Sub cat two
-Cat three
```

I added a node with the term `Sub cat two`.

I created a view formatted as table, listing node names and its assigned categories.

In this view, the category field only shows `Sub cat two` as result. As this term is a child of `Cat two`, I'd like to show something like `Cat two > Sub cat two` instead of just the child term.

I have no idea on how to achieve this.

Any hints?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That one was not and simple solution. I solved it this way:

1. I first installed [Views PHP module](https://drupal.org/project/views_php) and enabled it;
2. I created a content view for my content type formatted as a table;
3. In this view I created a new field of the type 'Global:PHP', and added the following to the "Value Code" textarea:

   ```
   $n = node_load($data->nid);
   $field = field_get_items('node', $n, 'field_tipo');
   $parents = taxonomy_get_parents_all($field[0]['tid']);
   $output = array();
   foreach($parents as $term) {
       array_unshift($output, $term->name);
   }

   return implode(' » ', $output);
   ```

And that's it!